# Azure Logic Apps: Check for File Size

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

When a file is uploaded onto an FTP server, I'd like to send a notification only if the file size is greater than 1KB.  Would using an expression to check the length of the file content work or is there a better approach?  It would be nice if there was a dynamic content for file size.

Comment: I was able to achieve this with the expression: length(string(triggerBody()))

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer for others to refer.

Answer (score 1):

The 'correct' approach would be to use the **Get file metadata** Action which returns a blob with a **Size** attribute.

This way, you do not have to retrieve the file to get the size.

Comment: Get file metadata -size Attribute will return the file size in KB or bytes??